# How to filter and loop through objects in a Django template

Tags: django, django-models

I'm modifying the default article.html template that came with Aldryn Newsblog to allow for a comment form and listing of the comments for that specific article. I have included the form without a problem. But I can't figure out how to query the comments.

**EDITED**

Here is my list_comments.html template:

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags %}
{% if comments %}
    {% for item in comments %}
    <div class="comment paragraph">
        <h4>{{ item.author }}</h4>
        <p>{{ item.comment }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No comments exist on this blog. Be the first to comment!</p>
{% endif %}
```

and comment_form.html

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags %}
<div id="comment_form">
<div class="container constrained paragraph">
    <h5>Submit a comment</h5>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ comment_form }}

        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ article.id }}">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment">
    </form>
</div>
```

And models.py:

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="IP Address")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    article = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

And in views.py I have these:

```
def display_form(request):
    comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'comment_form.html', {'comment_form': comment_form})


def get_blog_comments(request):
    qs = BlogComment.objects.all()
    context = {'comments': qs, 'another': 'test'}
    return render(request, 'list_comments.html', context)
```

And in both templates, the context variables are outputting nothing. I am at a loss for what I'm doing wrong. django.template.context_processors.request is included in my settings.py context_processors.

Comment: But that is not how Django works. Have you done the tutorial? You don't just define a function and refer to it in the template; you need a view, which passes the values as the template context.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay and I have a views.py with that function declared... I don't understand what else I need?

Comment: You're view still isn't correct. You need to return the query a dictionary.

Comment: The point isn't that the function is in views.py. The point is that the function *is a view*; it's pointed to by a URL, it accepts a request, it renders a template with context, and it returns a response. Your function doesn't do any of those things. Alain, please do the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, the querying is done in your views.py file.

```
# views.py
def get_blog_comments(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        qs = BlogComment.objects.all()
        template = # location of template, ex. blog_list.html
        context = {'obj_list': qs}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Is there a certain page in the documentation that you're referring to? I have read it and none of it seems relevant, which is why I'm here. Why do you check if the request method is GET? Is this a template for a single comment or all of them? How do I filter for the current article? What does my template look like to pass in a parameter, like the article name?

Comment: You check that the incoming request is of 'GET' method because you may later also want to use this view to 'POST' new comments. In order to filter for the current article you will need to pass the article's id.